# Modified question after accepting answer

Tags: discussion

I don't know whether it should be asked or not.

A day ago, I have answer on a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45278570/2315473). I was sure that, my answer is right. After few minutes later, the user accepted my answer.

Today, I have seen that my SO reputations decreased by `15`. I noticed my [Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2315473/sunkuet02?tab=reputation) section and found why this happened.

Then, I have gone to that post and charmed that he edited his question according to my answer and remove his acceptance.

Afterwards, in comments, I have asked him and his reply was [image]

My question is: Should we do such kind of work ? Or, what should I do in this kind of situations ?

Comment: That is codswallop...

Comment: @Jason it happens pretty often unfortunately. people do NOT realize that we are not a help desk site, and they act as if we are, disregarding our rules :(.  (btw thanks for the new word :P)

Comment: I know it does happen, it is just super frustrating. My comment was meant to commiserate with OP. I use that word all the time, even throughout college i would use it in my papers. Glad you like it!

Comment: @PaulRoub, The questions are not same as user has remove in acceptance in my case

Comment: @sunkuet02 That's irrelevant, the advice in the answers in the duplicate still applies. There's not much more you can - or should - do.

Comment: @yannis, I am confused shouldn't community revert that question in previous form ?

Comment: @sunkuet02 You can, yes, that's what the duplicate tells you you can do.

Comment: @Servy, If I will edit it then, will SO community accept it ?

Comment: @sunkuet02 If you explain that the question was changed to be a different question than was originally asked, then it should be accepted.  If you don't explain your edit properly then it would be correctly rejected as it would make it look like you are the one changing the question's meaning.

Comment: @Servy, I have updated it. Let's see what community will do. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I have reverted that post and community accepted it.